# When I click the cell, the image is stretch out

Tags: ios, imageview, cell, xib

This is the cell I created by `XIB`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But however, after I use tableView load the cells, I get the issue:

[image]

Comment: remove existing bottom constraint ...give bottom constraint with label .

Comment: set imageview.cliptoBound = yes;

Comment: just set imageview to scall to fit and your problem solve

Answer (score 0):

You need to change image scale as below :

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

**Swift 3**

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you used `Aspect Fill` in the attribute pannel. Thus the image width equal to the screen (as per your constraints) and keep its width*height ratio, but it is going outside bounds of your `imageView`.

You need to add in `viewDidLoad` or in your class file:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Check this link to [Apple's documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to clip the image out side bounds:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES
```

it will crop image to visible rect only

Answer (score 0):

If you design your cell in xib, you can set the Clip to Bounds in Drawing:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>